# What is the meaning of () inside a list eg. [()] in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5

I came across an h5py tutorial wherein a particular index of an hdf5 file is accessed as follows:

```
f = h5py.File('random.hdf5', 'r')
data = f['default'][()]
f.close()

print(data[10])
```

In this manner, even when the file is closed, the data is still accessible. It seems adding `[()]` no longer makes `data` a simple pointer, but rather the data object itself. What is the meaning of `[()]`?

Comment: Looks like they're indexing into a dict with an empty tuple? `{(): "foo"}[()]` which gives `"foo"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` is an empty [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). HDF5 datasets can have an arbitrary number of dimensions and support indexing, but some datasets are zero-dimensional (they store a single scalar value). For these, h5py uses indexing with an empty tuple `[()]` to access that value. You can't use `[0]` or even `[:]` because that implies at least one dimension to slice along.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused why it was indexed that way. This is a very neat principle.

Answer (score 0):

`()` is an empty tuple, and indexing with an empty tuple  is documented in [h5py's documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#creating-and-reading-empty-or-null-datasets-and-attributes):

> An empty dataset has shape defined as None, which is the best way of determining whether > a dataset is empty or not. An empty dataset can be “read” in a similar way to scalar > datasets, i.e. if empty_dataset is an empty dataset,:
>
> ```
> >>> empty_dataset[()]
> h5py.Empty(dtype="f")
> ```
>
> The dtype of the dataset can be accessed via .dtype as per normal. As empty > datasets cannot be sliced, some methods of datasets such as read_direct will raise an exception if used on a empty dataset.